# Using htonl/ntohl on a 32 bit integer that will be sent over a socket

Tags: c++, winsock

When I look up examples for htonl, it always returns a **uint32_t**. However, when I call htonl in VS2015 using Winsock2.h, it returns a **u_long**.

On my machine, when I compile for 32 bit and for 64 bit, I get that the size of a u_long is 4 bytes. I read online, that in a 64 bit architecture a long should be 8 bytes. Will this ever be the case? I am worried that I will have compatibility issues if a u_long is not the same amount of bytes as uint32_t when the data is to be sent over the socket.

TL;DR - Will a u_long always be 4 bytes? If not, how should you reliably send a 32 bit integer over a socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u_long` is a `typedef` to `unsigned long`, long in turn is (or should be) guaranteed to be at least 32 bits - that is at least 4 bytes. On some systems it may be larger - but there's really no way to know in advance.

So, when you do network communication and want to send integers that's larger than one byte you have to take care to restrict the size yourself. Don't just send `sizeof` bytes, restrict it to four bytes.

Also when dealing with integers you have the little matter of which byte order is used to send/receive the data.
If you have the same OS both sides, this won't be an issue - but if you switch between Windows and Linux for example, it could be.